# Pandas: Randomly splitting index values between 2 index values

Tags: python, pandas, random, series

This is an "ISO week 53 problem".

I have a pandas `Series` instance with index values representing the ISO week number:

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.Series([1,1,1,2,3,1,2], index=[1,1,2,2,52,53,53])
```

I want to randomly and equally replace all of the `index = 53` indices with either `index = 52` or `index = 1`.

For the above, this could be:

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.Series([1,1,1,2,3,1,2], index=[1,1,2,2,52,52,1])
```

or

```
import pandas as pd
ts = pd.Series([1,1,1,2,3,1,2], index=[1,1,2,2,52,1,52])
```

for example. **How do I do this, please?**

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

In numpy I used the following to achieve this:

```
from numpy import where
from numpy.random import shuffle

indices = where(timestamps == 53)[0]
number_of_indices = len(indices)
if number_of_indices == 0:
    return # no iso week number 53 to fix.
shuffle(indices) # randomly shuffle the indices.
midway_index = number_of_indices // 2
timestamps[indices[midway_index:]] = 52 # precedence if only 1 timestamp.
timestamps[indices[: midway_index]] = 1
```

where the `timestamps` array is the pandas `index` value.

Comment: are you talking about adding `.6` to every value?

Comment: @Chris I've re-formatted the question. I think just changing the index value randomly is sufficient.

Comment: What does 'randomly and equally' mean here? You want to replace all `53` values, half with `1` and half with `52`, and assigned randomly? What if there's an odd number of `53` values?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Please see the edit for how I achieved this using numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension should work if I understand you correctly:

```
ts = pd.Series([1,1,1,2,3,1,2], index=[1,1,2,2,52,53,53])
ts.index = [i if i != 53 else np.random.choice([1,52]) for i in ts.index]

1     1
1     1
2     1
2     2
52    3
52    1
1     2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Sure thing. Because you are working with a series the list comprehension should be pretty quick. I did a quick test with 1 million rows and it took a little less than `300 ms`